# Delete documents from collection and remove Ids from an array in another collection

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a reviews collection and a users collection. In the users collection I have docs that have an array called  `reviews` that contains the _ids of the review from the reviews collection. Sometimes I go to the mongo terminal and delete reviews from the reviews collection that I don't want from the reviews collection. for example I would  delete all that don't have a specific field. the problem is I would also like to delete the review id in the reviews array. I do a simple `db.collection.remove` on the reviews collection so that is easy.(that would delete like 50 reviews). I was wondering how to remove ids in the reviews array easily. Any ideas? I use mongoose but I was wondering if there was an easy way to do in the terminal. I think the only association is the ids.

I no how to use $pull but I want to make it pull the ids every time a specific review is removed.

Comment: can you post pieces of code that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can't do this with a single atomic update as you have two collections to update. What you can do is carry out two operations in series i.e. the removal of the specific reviews from the `reviews` collection and then use the **[`$pullAll`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/)** operator to delete the values from reviews array in the `users` collection.

The following mongo shell example shows this:

```
var reviewIds = [
    ObjectId("582ebf010936ac3ba5cd00e2"),
    ObjectId("582ebf010936ac3ba5cd00e3"),
    ...
];

db.reviews.remove({ "_id": { "$in": reviewIds } });
db.users.updateMany(
    { "reviews": { "$in": reviewIds } },
    { "$pullAll": { "reviews": reviewIds } }
);
```

For a single review id, you can just use the **[`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)** operator as

```
db.reviews.remove({ "_id": reviewId });
db.users.updateMany(
    { "reviews": reviewIds },
    { "$pull": { "reviews": reviewId } }
);
```